# how to solve the problem of "Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found"?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, dependencies

I am learning to write android apps by watching some tutorials on youtube. I follow the tutorials and try to add the recyclerview in the xml file. When I click the download button next to the recyclerview, the following message is shown:

"This operation requires the library androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:+.

Problem: Inconsistencies in the existing project dependencies found.
Version incompatibility between:
-   androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0@aar
and:
-   androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0@aar

With the dependency:
-   androidx.annotation:*:1.1.0
versus:
-   androidx.annotation:*:2.0.0

The project may not compile after adding this library.
Would you like to add it anyway?"

If I choose OK and go ahead, the preview screen becomes grey.

What should I do to solve the problem?

The same problem occurs when I want to add the cardview in the xml file.

thanks in advance!!!!

The build.gradle is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartherd.msgshareapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: I have solved my problem. Let me share to see whether it is helpful. 

holland.pk/uptow/i4/fb987a06a34375218dd7be723d6b8661.jpg 

Please look at the image in the link above. The exclamation mark is marked with a red circle. Click on that exclamation mark and follow the instruction in the message box after adding the recyclerview and producing the grey preview screen. The problem will be solved. The recycler view can be shown properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just build the project again and manually refresh the layout. :)